# why are comment objects not deleted from database although the view is triggered?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I try to remove comment so, I tried the first time by the class-based view then I hashed it to try the second way by normal function to know what's going on here. so, when I try to delete the comment by ID nothing does happen it's just directing me to the web page without deleting the comment so in this case the program runs but doesn't remove the object so, what is going on here?
Note: the posts and comments on the same page and slug field on that page are following by post not comment. 
if the title of the post is: new title so, the slug will be new-title depending on the post

question_view.html

```
    <div class="user-answer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {% for comment in my_question.comment_set.all %}
                        <div class="comments">
                            <div class="col-xs-0">
                                <div class="avatar">
                                    <a href="{% url 'account:view_profile' comment.username %}">
                                        <img class="img-circle img-thumbnail" style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{{ comment.logo }}">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                 <!-- --Comment itself-- -->
                                <div class="user_comment">
                                    <p>{{ comment }}</p>
                                    <div class="fa fa-caret-left comment-arrow"></div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- start Options in comment -->
                                <div class="sub-options">
                                    {% if request.user.username == comment.username %}
                                    <!-- --Edit comment-- -->
                                    <div class="edit-comment">
                                        <a>Edit</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- --Delete comment-- -->
                                    <div class="delete-comment">
                                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'community:delete_comment' comment.pk %}">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <input type="hidden" name="delete-comment" value="{{ comment.comment }}">
                                            <input type="submit" value="delete">
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <!-- end Options in comment -->
                                    <!-- --comment Date-- -->
                                    <div style="display: inline-block;color: #8e8e8e" class="comment-date">
                                        <p>{{ comment.date|time }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

views.py

```
# Delete post
# class DeleteComment(DeleteView, SingleObjectMixin):
#     model = Comment
#     pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
#     template_name = 'community/question_view.html'
#     queryset = Comment.objects.all()
#
#     def get_success_url(self):
#         title = UserAsking.objects.get(title=self.object)
#         slug = UserAsking.objects.get(title=title).ask_slug
#         return reverse_lazy('community:question_view', kwargs={'user_slug': slug})
#
#     def get_object(self, queryset=None):
#         request_comment = self.request.POST['delete-comment']
#         return self.get_queryset().filter(pk=request_comment).get()

def delete_comment(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=pk)
    del comment
    return redirect('community:user_questions')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('delete-comment/<int:pk>/', views.DeleteComment.as_view(), name="delete_comment"),
    path('delete-comment/<int:pk>/', views.delete_comment, name="delete_comment"),
]
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    userasking = models.ForeignKey(UserAsking, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default='empty')
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/default-logo.jpg', blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default='empty')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

I hope if you can explain by class based-view what's happening I will appreciate that.
note that: if you could understand exactly what's happening you will know that is no error appears to me, therefore, I get no exception or traceback. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
def delete_comment(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=pk).delete()
    return redirect('community:user_questions')
```

Your function only deletes the object but not the database entry since you don't trigger a valid SQL operation (delete in this case).

You just delete the object `comment` again which was assigned previously, but you don't affect the database entry:

```
def delete_comment(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=pk)
    del comment
    return redirect('community:user_questions')
```

More on `delete()` in the official docu:

> [Deleting objects¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete)

**Update on your comment:**

You can't use Python's `del` statement to interact with database entries in Django.
Pythons `del` statement is used to delete objects initially created by Python like lists, variables, etc. etc.

In order to interact with your database in Django, you have to use the toolbox of Django's built-in [Model instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete) which basically translates raw SQL operations into easy to use methods.

So maybe you can adapt a proper wording to highlight the differences by calling database "objects" **entries** and python objects: well, **objects**..

However, Django still offers the option to use [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/) as fallback.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas.the delete method is removing objects from the database. but, I want to know when can I use del?